# the label does not show the photo from the class - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

please give me a hand! i have one simple WPF project, which it doesn't show the image. i have been struggling with it since one week, can not find my mistake! i looked a lot the solutions on this website, but still did not help me!

C# Code from Display Window

```
 public partial class Boatdetails : Window
    {

        //public Boatdetails()
        public Boatdetails(Object boot)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (boot is Ruderboot)
            {
                modell.Content = ((Ruderboot)boot).Modell;
                plaetze.Content = ((Ruderboot)boot).Plaetze;
                preis.Content = ((Ruderboot)boot).Preis;
                bild.Content = ((Ruderboot)boot).Image;
                HoheStack.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                MoroStack.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else if (boot is Segelboote)
            {
                modell.Content = ((Segelboote)boot).Modell;
                plaetze.Content = ((Segelboote)boot).Plaetze;
                preis.Content = ((Segelboote)boot).Preis;
                bild.Content = ((Segelboote)boot).Image;
                hohe.Content = ((Segelboote)boot).Height;
                HoheStack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                MoroStack.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else
            {
                modell.Content = ((Motorboot)boot).Modell;
                plaetze.Content = ((Motorboot)boot).Plaetze;
                preis.Content = ((Motorboot)boot).Preis;
                bild.Content = ((Motorboot)boot).Image;
                motorModel.Content = ((Motorboot)boot).MotorModel;
                motoLeistung.Content = ((Motorboot)boot).EnginePerformence;
                HoheStack.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                MoroStack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }


            BitmapImage jpg = new BitmapImage(new Uri(((Boote)boot).Image, UriKind.Relative)); //Bild setzten, relativ im ordner images
            Image img = new Image();
            img.Source = jpg;
            bild.Content = img; 

        }


        private void showDetails(object detail)  
        {

                spDetail.Height = 27; 
                lblDetails.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; 
                details.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        }
    }
```

and XML Window Code

```
 <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Bild:" Width="100"/>
            <Label x:Name="bild" Width="200" Height="200"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Modell:" Width="100"/>
            <Label x:Name="modell" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Plätze:" Width="100"/>
            <Label x:Name="plaetze" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="spDetail" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="0">
            <Label x:Name="lblDetails" Content="Details:" Width="100" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <Label x:Name="details" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Preis:" Width="100"/>
            <Label x:Name="preis" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Name="HoheStack"
                    Visibility="Visible">
            <Label Content="Hohe:" Width="100"/>
            <Label x:Name="hohe" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="MoroStack"
                    Visibility="Visible">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    Visibility="Visible">
                <Label Content="Moto Modell:" Width="100"/>
                <Label x:Name="motorModel" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Leistung" Width="100"/>
                <Label x:Name="motoLeistung" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
```

this is how i have added object into the class:

```
 rl.Add(new Ruderboot() { Modell = "XLight", Plaetze = 1, Preis = 3400, Image = "./Images/ruderboot1.jpg" });
```

and my class

```
 public class Boote
    {
        public string Modell { get; set; }
        public sbyte Plaetze { get; set; }
        public float Preis { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Modell + ": "+ Preis+"€";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure the image file path is a valid relative path. Is there is a fixed number of image files or are these supposed to be added dynamically at runtiime?

Comment: You would usually not use a Label to show an image. Replace the Label declaration in XAML by `<Image x:Name="image" .../>` and set `image.Source = new BitmapImage(...);` in code behind.

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply! the image path is absolutely correct! only few more images in the folder, which are not assigned to any object yet.

Comment: So you mean when your program runs in Visual Studio e.g. in Debug mode, there is a folder "YourProject\bin\Debug\Images\" where the image files are located?

Comment: i've one folder into my solution '''Images''' and inside this folder are the images with exact names

Comment: So their path is "YourProject\Images\..." while your program runs in "YourProject\bin\Debug\"

Comment: i tried your code, but the boot class property (Image) is string, therefore it shows error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Build Action of the image files in your project to `Resource` (Solution Explorer -> Context Menu -> Properties) and load them by [Resource File Pack URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris) like

```
Image = "pack://application:,,,/Images/ruderboot1.jpg"
```

Besides that, you should use data binding. Assign the passed boat object to the DataContext of the Window:

```
public Boatdetails(Object boot)
{
    DataContext = boot;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

In XAML, just write expressions like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Modell}"/>
<Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
```

where in the latter case the conversion from `string` to `ImageSource` is performed automatically by the framework.

---

You could use a single ContentControl with different DataTemplates for different boat types, like

```
<Window x:Class="BoatdetailsTest.Boatdetails" ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Ruderboot}">
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- elements for Ruderboot -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Segelboot}">
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- elements for Segelboot -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! i have many objects, should i specify each object images like this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, of course you have to set the Image property of every boat. If there is a single image for every *type of boat*, you can drop the Image property and assign the Image Source property directly in the DataTemplate for that type.